# Importing Class in GSPs in IntelliJ IDE

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

I use:

- IntelliJ Idea 15.0
- Grails 2.4.3

If I want to import a class to my gsp for example

```
${User}
```

IDE adds the path as

```
${de.foo.bar.foo.User}
```

and add this on the top

```
<%@ page import="de.foo.bar.foo.User" %> //This is not the Problem
```

How can I prevent that IDE doesn't add the path on my gsp instead adds it where the class is used in gsp as below:

```
<%@ page import="de.foo.bar.foo.User" %> ${User}
```

Comment: If IDE is using absolute package path then it won't be adding an import. If it is it shouldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IntelliJ I can press Alt+Enter and can replace the path with an import